# How to disable Cane Abc Complexity

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i am working on a RoR project. I want to disable Cane ABC Complexity.
Whenever i run my unit test it throws error:

```
Methods exceeded maximum allowed ABC complexity (1):
```

Please help me to disable it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What Rubocop version are you using? Is your yml file working for other rules?

Comment: This message is like to be from Cane, not RuboCop: http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cane/2.2.1

Comment: Thanks but how to disable it?

Comment: cane.abc_max = 15 is set but my code is working on 22 should i change it 15 to 22 or i should fix it?

Comment: i tried cane.abc_exclude = %w(Interactors::ParserDateTimeInteractor.find_date_time(params)) but its not working. Please help